# AVPlayer resizeAspect works only properly on iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcomposition, avvideocomposition

resizeAspect as the video gravity only works properly for me, when using an iPhone X.

For some reasons, the black aspect bar gets only added to the top and not to the bottom. This is how it looks like when I'm not using an iPhone X (the image is white)

[image: iphone]

This is how it should look like:

[image: normal state]

As you can see, on the iPhone X, everything looks clean and balanced as expected.

This is how I play the video:

```
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    avPlayerLayer.frame = PreviewLayer.bounds
    avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect //Will automatically add black bars


    PreviewLayer.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: video)
    avPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    avPlayer?.play()
```

Comment: try this  `avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill`

Comment: and check this view `PreviewLayer` bottom constraint  first item  safe area

Comment: I need .resizeAspect, not . resizeAspectFill.

Comment: please add full code what this `PreviewLayer` UIView ?

Comment: PreviewLayer is just a simple and plain UIView, that is stretched to the safeLayout

Comment: ok , Check my answer and look  note :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your videoLayer View a subview of:

```
class VideoContainerView: UIView {

    var playerLayer: CALayer?

    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
        playerLayer?.frame = self.bounds
    }

}
```

and add:

```
self.VideoShareLayer.playerLayer = avPlayerLayer;
```

before inserting the layer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this steps

1- Check bottom constraint connect with safe are

[image]

2- Try this code

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: UIView!
    private var player: AVPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       playVideo(from: "Intro.mp4")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    private func playVideo(from file:String) {
        let file = file.components(separatedBy: ".")

        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file[0], ofType:file[1]) else {
            debugPrint( "\(file.joined(separator: ".")) not found")
            return
        }

        player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player.currentItem, queue: .main) { _ in
            self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.player?.play()
        }

        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
        playerLayer.frame = playerView.layer.bounds
        playerView.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 0)
        player.play()
    }

}
```

Result on iphone X

[image]

Result on iphone 7

[image]

> Note : if you need video full view on all devices try to link `Bottom
>   constraint` and `Top constraint` with superview not with safe area